# Let $A$ be $m\times n$ and $B$ be $n\times m$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Let $A_{m\times n},B_{n\times m}$ be two different non-zero matrices, then what is wrong with the following proof:

If $AB=I_m$, then we have:$B(AB)=B\implies(BA)B=B\implies(BA-I_n)B=O_{n\times n}\implies BA=I_{n}$

Note that I have a counterexample for $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&&0&&0\\0&&1&&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1&&0\\0&&1\\0&&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: $UV=0_{n\times n}$ does not imply $U=0$ or $V=0$, just $U$ and $V$ not both regular...

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS thanks, but what do you mean by regular? and why does this argument work in case of square matrices?

Comment: regular means invertible (ergo simplifiable). And the argument does not work even in case of square matrices : $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the implication $(BA)B=B \implies (BA-I_n)B=O_{n\times n}$ is not true: the size of the matrix on the right hand side is incorrect, it should be an $n\times m$ matrix.

The next implication is incorrect as well: matrix rings usually have [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor), which means that $(BA-I_n)B=O_{n\times m}$ does not imply that $BA-I_n=O_{n\times n}$ or $B=O_{n\times m}$.

Comment: thanks, such a silly mistake.